# Bulid error on Travis CI to Django 3.0.3 on GitHub repo

Tags: django, python-3.6, travis-ci

After adding .travis.yml file to project directory, travis ci is giving me errors that I can't solve.
.travis.yml looks like this:

```
language: python
python:
  - "3.7"
# command to install dependencies
install:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
# command to run tests
script: pytest
```

The error I get is:

```
Worker information
0.14s0.01s0.00s0.01s
system_info
Build system information
0.01s0.00s0.35s0.21s0.05s0.00s0.04s0.00s0.01s0.01s0.01s0.01s0.01s0.00s0.00s0.02s0.00s0.01s0.30s0.00s0.00s0.00s0.01s0.00s0.12s0.01s0.81s0.00s0.00s6.03s0.00s2.73s0.00s2.28s
docker_mtu
resolvconf
git.checkout
1.05s$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=master https://github.com/ChrisAchinga/The-Diary.git ChrisAchinga/The-Diary
0.01s0.01s$ source ~/virtualenv/python3.7/bin/activate
$ python --version
Python 3.7.1
$ pip --version
pip 19.0.3 from /home/travis/virtualenv/python3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
install
10.77s$ pip install -r requirements.txt
0.40s$ pytest
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.1, pytest-4.3.1, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.0
rootdir: /home/travis/build/ChrisAchinga/The-Diary, inifile:
collected 0 items                                                              
========================= no tests ran in 0.05 seconds =========================
The command "pytest" exited with 5.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

[The error from travis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juVy3.png)

The link to github: https://github.com/ChrisAchinga/The-Diary

Comment: You don't actually have any tests in your project... hence why pytest returns with [exit code 5](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#possible-exit-codes).

Comment: So if I remove the test script i"ll be good